# TFSA Withdrawals

Tags: canada, tfsa, withdrawal

If my TFSA is worth $25000 and I only put in for 2 years ($10000), can I withdraw the $25000 and put it back in later, or am I only allowed to put the original $10000 back in (assuming this withdrawal and subsequent redeposit is done in the same calendar year)?

Comment: I want to know what product you put that 10k into!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can make out from [CRA site](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/tfsa-celi/wthdrwls-eng.html) it seems that you can definitely *not* redeposit in the same year (as I originally incorrectly answered to someone else, but have since corrected).

It does appear, however, that you can withdraw as much as you like, and that would generate room for the *subsequent* year.

Good Luck

Comment: This is what I understand, too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it works like this:
(Note, I am assuming you were 18 on Jan 1 2009)

Contribution limits:

- 2009: 5000
- 2010: 5000
- 2011: 5000
- 2012: 5000

So by the end of 2012, you will have been allowed to contribute $20,000 of **new** money.

You say you've contributed $10,000, so you still can contribute another $10,000 of **new** money this year (But let's assume you do not...).

Now, your original $10,000 has grown to $25,000.  You can withdraw this without penalty.  Next year, you will be given an allotment of another $5000 of new money (bringing your total lifetime limit to $25,000 - $10,000 = $15,000 new money) PLUS, you will be allowed to re-contribute up to $25,000 of OLD money.

Of course, the government doesn't make a distinction between old and new money, so the net effect is (assuming a 25k withdrawal):

2012 limit: $10 000
2013 limit: $40 000 less 2012 contributions.

From http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/tfsa-celi/cntrbtn-eng.html:

> *The TFSA contribution room is made up of*:
>
> - *your TFSA dollar limit ($5,000 per year plus indexation, if applicable)*;
> - *any unused TFSA contribution room from the previous year*; and
> - *any withdrawals made from the TFSA in the previous year, excluding qualifying transfers or specified distributions.*

From this wording, it means the 25 k you withdraw will go to the 2013 contribution room (bullet 3).  If you don't re-contribute, it will roll over into the 2014 contribution room (Under bullet 2)

For correctness, I must add that I did not include any indexing of the annual amount.